# Problem with my custom framework (Xcode swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I have created a **custom framework** in which i have installed some **pods**. Now when I link a sample project with my custom framework and build it, I'm getting errors like

> " could not find auto-linked framework 'xxxx' ".

Here `'xxxx'` is the pod name  that I installed in my custom framework project.

Comment: you need to check your custom framework is added to linked framework and library in setting

Comment: Yes it is linked in the sample project.

Comment: I think the problem is, in my custom framework I can see 2 frameworks, 1 is custom.framework and other is Pods_custom.framework. So when I link my  custom .framework to my sample project, it is showing error that it cannot find autolinked framework which is a pod I installed in my custom framework

Comment: you custom framework without pod working ? if yes then check only pod_custom.framework and see what error you see.

Comment: There is no error in pod_custom.framework. My custom framework code is dependent on a pod so I installed it in my custom framework. And I can able to build the custom framework without any error. Now when I link my custom.framework to a sample app, I'm able to see all the classes in my custom framework and use it but when I try to build the sample project it is throwing the error I mentioned. I think the custom.framework is dependent on the Pods_custom.framework, so any way to merge them ?

Comment: I had this problem with a Pod (SQLite in this case), found this question and a similar one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54651151/519030) and had to add: "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/SQLite.swift" to the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS of the app's target.

I'd add this as an answer but I'm not convinced I am doing it the correct way.