# Cannot fix "Could not find or use auto-linked library "

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app built with Swift with pods(firebase). I have 18 warnings and 100 errors which weren't there before. They only appear when I try to archive my app.

I have tried all of these
(Adding search paths, Adding blank swift files, deleting framework paths)

[It gives errors when using Swift Static library with Objective-C project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096025/it-gives-errors-when-using-swift-static-library-with-objective-c-project/50495316#50495316)

[Why do I get iOS linker errors with my static libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536380/why-linker-link-static-libraries-with-errors-ios/54586937#54586937)

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftGLKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftSpriteKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftModelIO'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreAudio'
```

Environment: Xcode 11 beta 4 / Target: iOS 12 and up

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apple mentioned similar issue in [known issues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_4_release_notes#3359258) section:

> Targets that contain Swift code with the Enable Bitcode
>   build setting set to Yes fail to link correctly when built with the
>   Archive action.

And give us a workaround:

> Add a custom build setting with
>   the name LD_VERIFY_BITCODE, and set it to NO. Make a note to yourself
>   to delete this custom build setting once this issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks. You made my day!

Comment: For me actually, before I noticed this answer I deleted all of my pods and reinstalled them and that fixed it for me

Comment: I am facing a similar issue while building my `react-native` code for iOS. This solution isn't working for me. Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: Same issue as @LordAnari . Also getting this in react-native. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: @KentAgent which library are you manually linking? For me, I am trying `react-native-razorpay`. Just wondering if it has anything to do with this.

Comment: @LordAnari I managed to solve my issue. Please check my answer on another question here and see if that solves your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61582562/8576909

Answer (score 16):

My ObjectiveC project was including a Swift pod which was then throwing the above errors. I found all I had to do was add a swift header file into the base of my project and it suddenly all built.

What gave it away for me was when I went into the Build Settings of my Target project and did a search for 'swift' I was only seeing a very minimal amount of results when I knew I should be seeing more - after adding the header file I suddenly saw a lot more options here. Below are the steps I took.

1. Right click on your root project in the Project Navigator
2. Select 'New File'
3. Select a 'Swift File'
4. Give it a name of 'BridgeHeader' (you don't need to specify the .swift - it'll add the extension automatically)
5. Run a clean + build and hopefully the errors will have disappeared!

I'm unsure if the name is important, nor am I sure on the position of the file but this is what worked for me!

Comment: Seems to go away when you add the bridging header

Comment: Works! should be the accepted answer.  Had this issue when using #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKSettings.h> and setting setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled and it fixed my issue as I was building in Objective C

Answer (score 5):

I had a same error... my problem solved with -> add the library (framework) in the `Frameworks and Libraries` that you used in any target

for Example :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was a React-Native project after adding a Swift Pods library.

## Solution 1:

1. Adding a new Swift file and a Bridge header:

1. `File -> New -> File`
   [image: File -> New -> File]
2. Select `Swift File` [image: Select Swift File]
3. Confirm `Create Bridging Header` [image]

## Solution 2:

1. Go to `Build Settings` and set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `YES` [image: Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries]

Comment: This is the solution :) Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

Create a swift file in the main project (File.swift) and add the following code to the same

```
//
// File.swift
//
import Foundation
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you see the issue after updating React Native from 0.63.x to [0.64.x](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2021/03/12/version-0.64), try this solution:

- Create a new 0.64.x project:

  ```
  npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
  ```
- Compare `package.json` of the new project and of your old 0.63.x project, and modify the old one.
- Do similarly with `ios/Podfile`.
- Run `yarn install` or `npm install`.
- Run `pod install` in `ios` directory. Probably you need to remove the old `Podfile.lock` file.
- Now, when you rebuild your project, hopefully the issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I accidentally added a test file to the main swift target. Removing it solves the problem

Here are what I did

### 1. go to compile source for the main target

[image]

### 2. search for test

[image]

### 3. remove it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue but the offending class was a unit test class. It turned out that a pod reference in my podfile was not included in the test target.

Answer (score 0):

I had added a new test target. I forgot to update my Podfile for the test target. Make sure you add your new target to Podfile. Run "pod deintegrate" and "pod install" after it.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all of these and the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767974/auto-linking-framework-not-found) I reverted and made two simple changes. I added `import Foundation` to the test file and then I added the offending pod to my testing target in the podfile. That resolved the issue.