# AppAuth not signed at all when adding firebase to xcode project

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods, xcode12

I'm trying to add firebase to an existing project but I keep getting errors on building and after a couple of days searching the internet I have not yet fixed the issue :(

I've tried adding --deep to the signing flags, locking and unlocking the keychain, switching to `use_modular_headers!` in the Podfile.

I don't have a physical device to test on.

My Podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
#platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'EyeArtifact' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # Pods for EyeArtifact
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'FirebaseUI'

  pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/OAuth'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Phone'

  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'

  # Facebook pods
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', :modular_headers => true

end
```

and my error is:

```
/Users/jvines/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-bgaqkzrrqevduaadrswisdyouwqv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/***.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework: replacing existing signature
/Users/jvines/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-bgaqkzrrqevduaadrswisdyouwqv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/***.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework: code object is not signed at all
In architecture: x86_64
```

If I switch between `use_frameworks!` and `use_modular_headers!` I get another error: `BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap' not found` when building

I've tried disabling the signing script when building but then if I run the app I get this error: `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth`

The simulator is running iOS 14.2 and I'm using Xcode 12

I also tried a brand new project and adding the frameworks from scratch but I encountered the same errors.

I'm new to iOS development so any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you :)

Comment: Try `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`

Comment: That creates a bunch of errors saying could not find or use 'swiftXXXX', which leads to like 100 undefined symbol messages :( Am I missing a step here??

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62172769/14828440

In short I was missing the bridging header even though I don't have any swift files.