# Problem when build relase version for ios "Swift.String.lowercased() -> Swift.String"

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-track-player

I have started build relase version for ios below is error which I received:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMediaPlayer'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreAudio'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "Swift.String.lowercased() -> Swift.String", referenced from:
      react_native_track_player.MediaURL.init(object: Any?) -> react_native_track_player.MediaURL? in libreact-native-track-player.a(MediaURL.o)
  "_swift_storeEnumTagSinglePayloadGeneric", referenced from:
      storeEnumTagSinglePayload value witness for react_native_track_player.MediaURL in libreact-native-track-player.a(MediaURL.o)
  "(extension in Foundation):__C.NSNumber.init(integerLiteral: Swift.Int) -> __C.NSNumber", referenced from:
      react_native_track_player.Capability.mapToPlayerCommand(forwardJumpInterval: __C.NSNumber?, backwardJumpInterval: __C.NSNumber?, likeOptions: [Swift.String : Any]?, dislikeOptions: [Swift.String : Any]?, bookmarkOptions: [Swift.String : Any]?) -> SwiftAudioEx.RemoteCommand in libreact-native-track-player.a(Capabilities.o)
```

Does anyone has any idea what might be causing this error. The answer is that the bridg file is missing, but I already checked it.

Comment: Google found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096863/cannot-fix-could-not-find-or-use-auto-linked-library/64750852 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536380/why-do-i-get-ios-linker-errors-with-my-static-libraries

Comment: It might help to provide some context. What version xcode, what language are you using what versions and if possible what area of the code (though I know this last one is a bit of a stretch as its a build issue)