# Swift 5: Undefined Symbol for Swift Static Library with Objective C Framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I've been cracking my head the past few days trying to solve this but I have absolutely no clue.
I've created a static library in Swift and it requires an Objective-C framework to perform certain features. The static lib builds fine until I used it in a testing Swift Project.

The Objective-C framework is giving errors:

[image]

I am in desperate need of help, or some sort of understanding. I'm a bit slow in this; thank you for your assistance in advance.

**The Swift static library:**

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the framework has been imported inside.
Static library target settings:

- Linking -> Other Linker Flags: -ObjC
- Linking -> Runpath Search Paths: $(inherited), @executable_path/Frameworks, @loader_path/Frameworks
- Search Paths -> Framework Search Paths: $(inherited), $(PROJECT_DIR)/TestSDK
- Search Paths -> Header Search Paths: nothing
- Search Paths -> Library Search Paths: nothing
- Swift Compiler - Search Paths -> Import Paths: nothing

**The test Swift project that's hosting the static library:**

[image]

- Linking -> Other Linker Flags: -ObjC
- Linking -> Runpath Search Paths: $(inherited), @executable_path/Frameworks, @loader_path/Frameworks
- Search Paths -> Framework Search Paths: $(inherited), $(PROJECT_DIR)
- Search Paths -> Header Search Paths: nothing
- Search Paths -> Library Search Paths: $(inherited), $(PROJECT_DIR)
- Swift Compiler - Search Paths -> Import Paths: $(PROJECT_DIR)

I have a hard time trying to understand the theory behind this. I hope I can finally solve & understand how it works after this. Even the smallest help will be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Is the framework built for x86_64?  Also, see suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767974/auto-linking-framework-not-found

Comment: Check the static framework xcode project `Build Active Architecture only` setting. https://medium.com/macoclock/deep-drive-xcode-build-settings-827c3ce4811c