# Azure iOS pipeline: ld: framework not found MapboxAccounts

Tags: ios, swift, azure-devops, configuration, mapbox-ios

[image]

1. Run successfully on local mac book
2. Using iOS 14
3. Show error: ld: framework not found MapboxAccounts (using Mapbox)
4. Yaml file:

```yaml
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macos-latest'
    
    variables:
    - group: Mapbox
    - name: configuration
      value: 'Debug'
    - name: sdk
      value: 'iphoneos'
    - name: scheme
      value: 'Mobile'
    
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "machine api.mapbox.com" > ~/.netrc
        echo "login mapbox" >> ~/.netrc
        echo "password $(sdkDownloadToken)" >> ~/.netrc
    
    - task: CocoaPods@0
      displayName: 'Pod installing'
      inputs:
        forceRepoUpdate: false
    
    - task: Xcode@5
      displayName: 'Building'
      inputs:
        actions: 'clean build'
        scheme: '$(scheme)'
        sdk: '$(sdk)'
        configuration: '$(configuration)'
        xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
        xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, 11, default, specifyPath
        packageApp: false
```

5. Any help and thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Azure iOS pipeline: ld: framework not found MapboxAccounts

According to the warning:

[image]

It seems that you save the framework under the local folder `User/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/De` instead of the project folder. Obviously this folder has not been added to our repo, so when we execute the build on the hosted agent, the files we need do not exist in that folder.

To resolve this issue, we need copied the .framework folder over to project/solution, then set the correct `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`.

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767974/auto-linking-framework-not-found) for some more details.